# Angular: RxWeb unique() validator not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have implemented a form that has a `FormArray`. In the `FormArray`, one control needs to have a unique value throughout the array. The `unique()` validator from RxWeb is working fine normally but the issue is working when I am pushing values in the `FormArray` manually it is not triggering the `unique()` validator. An example method mentioned below which is called on a button click:

```
abc() {
  let skillsArray = <FormArray>this.jobFormGroup.controls.skills;
  skillsArray.removeAt(0);
  const arr = [
    { skillName: 'A' },{ skillName: 'A' },
  ];
  arr.forEach(item => skillsArray.push(this.formBuilder.group(item)))
}
```

[image: error]

None of the field is highlighed as red.

[image: correct]

Highlighted in red when I enter data from UI.

You can use this [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/unique-value-validation-in-formarray-reactive-for-nempha?file=src/app/app.component.html) for playing around with the issue. Please click on the "Trigger Issue" button to create the issue shown in Image 1.

Answer (score 1):

Because your function abc() does not add the controls with the unique validator

```
 const arr = [
{ skillName:['A',RxwebValidators.unique()] },{ skillName: 
    ['A',RxwebValidators.unique()] },
];
```

Comment: this is working but why we need to add validator also while adding values?